# NoMethodError Sinatra Modular app

Tags: ruby, methods, sinatra, helper

Probably something quite basic but I want to be able to use some custom helper methods in a modular Sinatra app. I have the following in ./helpers/aws_helper.rb

```
helpers do
 def aws_asset( path )
   File.join settings.asset_host, path
 end
end
```

and then in my view i want to be able to use this method like so

```
<%= image_tag(aws_asset('/assets/images/wd.png')) %>
```

but i get the above area, so within my app.rb file i am

```
require './helpers/aws_helper'


class Profile < Sinatra::Base

get '/' do
  erb :index
end

end
```

So is my issue that i am requiring it outside of my Profile class. which doesn't make sense as I am requiring my config files for ENV variables the same way and they are being read, but then again they are not methods so i guess that does make sense.

I think maybe im struggling to get my head around what a modular app is as opposed to using a classic styled sinatra app.

Any pointers appreciated

Error message

```
NoMethodError at / undefined method `aws_asset' for #<Profile:0x007f1e6c4905c0> file: index.erb location: block in singletonclass line: 8
```

Comment: Are you really missing an apostrophe at the end of your `require` line? What is the actual full error message you are getting?

Comment: no, that was a typo, have amended, i have also added the error i get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `helpers do ...` in the top level like this you are adding the methods as helpers to `Sinatra::Application` and *not* your `Profile` class. If you are using the Sinatra modular style exclusively make sure you only ever use `require 'sinatra/base'`, and not `require sinatra`, this will prevent you from mixing up the two styles like this.

In this case you should probably create a module for your helpers instead of using `helpers do ...`, and then add that module with the [`helpers` method](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers) in your `Profile` class.

In `helpers/aws_helper.rb`:

```
module MyHelpers # choose a better name of course

  def aws_asset( path )
    File.join settings.asset_host, path
  end
end
```

In `app.rb`:

```
class Profile < Sinatra::Base

  helpers MyHelpers # include your helpers here

  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end
end
```